# how to change the background colour in a responsive email

Tags: responsive-design, html-email

I'm currently creating a responsive email although I'm struggling to get the highlighted panel (see the red border) to be coloured in grey. I'm using tables to structure the email.  Can anyone advise why this isn't working please?

Many thanks,

**The panel highlighted in red should be completely grey**
 [image]

Please refer to my Plunker available here: http://plnkr.co/edit/qTeN9hUGoko2090Iy8f3?p=preview

**Snippet of code**

```
<table class="payment-details" bgcolor="#fff">
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td class="header container">

    <div class="content">
      <table bgcolor="#333">  <!-- HELP - this doesn't colour the entire panel -->
      <tr>
          <td style="color: #fff; font-weight: bold; padding: 10px;">
            example text
          </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

  </td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the comments, I've updated the Plunker and it does work although the colouring bleeds across the width of the page, can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table bgcolor="#333">  <!-- THIS OPENS HERE -->
  <tr>
      <td style="color: #fff; font-weight: bold; padding: 10px;">
        example text
      </td>
  </tr>
</table> <!-- AND CLOSES HERE--->
```

The Table you have circled with Red in the screenshot is below that -

```
<!------------------------------------ 
---- BODY ----------------------------
------------------------------------->

<table class="head-wrap" bgcolor="#ccc">
```

So you'll need to add the background color to that table element instead.

Comment: thanks for your comments - i've updated the plunker although see my comment above

Comment: If you nest another table inside the td with the class 'header container', and give that the background color property. It will constrain the width. Forked Plnker here http://plnkr.co/edit/NnTSFXqDfJEruBuTSN0J

Answer (score 0):

If you add style="background-color: #333333;" to your TDs it should work. I would also suggest using #333333 instead of #333 as some clients don't support shorthand hex codes.

Comment: thanks for your comments - i've updated the plunker although see my comment above